# Facebook LikeBox on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, facebook

My likebox facebook works correctly in normal way. I want to do for performance in that way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#facebook-likebox").mouseenter(function(){
jQuery("#facebook-likebox").append('<div style="background: white;" class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx" data-width="292" data-height="410" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="light" data-border-color="#197597" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>');

});
});
```

But it not works. How can I turn off likebox fb when page is loading[not async]?

Comment: you want to remove that on mouse out ??

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll have to load the Facebook JavaScript SDK. Once you have that initialized, you'll be able to call `FB.XFBML.parse()`.

> [Taken from the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) -
>
> This function parses and renders XFBML markup in a document on the
>   fly. This could be used if you send XFBML from your server via ajax
>   and want to render it client side.

So what you would have to do, is on your `mouseenter` event call this function on the element containing the Facebook plugin -

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('facebook-likebox'));
```

---

Once the user has hovered over the area with the plugin, you should simply hide and display it (to preserve functionality). Right now your code would add it every time the mouse enters that area. There is no need to load it more than once.